# SharePoint 2010 Team Site Mystery SPANs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When checking the HTML source of a SharePoint 2010 Team site, I saw something very strange. There are a number of  tags at the end of the file, AFTER the closing HTML tag. I have no idea where these are coming from as they are not in the master page.  I have asked a colleague to check this on his SharePoint server and he sees the same thing.

Anyone have any ideas where this comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is provided at this post http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Get-rid-of-the-annoying-SPAN-tags-in-SharePoint-2010-pages.aspx